Firestore triggers without firebase functions
I have a nestjs backend that I would like to deploy to cloud run. The only issue is that when developing locally I would like to be able to use the firestore triggers. To my knowledge, the only way to accomplish this would be to create a bunch of firebase functions and call my nestjs api routes in firebase emulators. I know I can trigger cloud run with firestore triggers on production, but I want to be able to do it locally as well. Are there any solutions to this?
Thanks!
